# What is the meaning of these principal components?

Tags: pca, dataset, svd

I have a matrix of data. I computed the principal components of my matrix using SVD (code shown below):

subtract mean...then

$$[U,S,V] = SVD({\rm matrix})$$

for $V$, which is the principal components, I obtain the following values:

$$
   V =  \begin{matrix}
   \text{Noise}     &-0.2344  & 0.9548   & -0.0170  & 0.0947   & 0.1551   \\
   \text{Size}      &-0.9643  & -0.2296  &  0.0853  &  0.0666  & -0.0753  \\
   \text{Speed}     &0.0890   &  0.0479  &  0.9869  &  0.0770  & -0.0993  \\
   \text{Electric}  &0.0079   & -0.1823  &  0.0658  &  0.4101  &  0.8912  \\
   \text{Lorry}     &-0.0847  &  0.0045  &  0.1187  & -0.9014  & 0.4077   \\ 
    \end{matrix}
$$

How do I interpret these data and how am I suppose to know if any of these correlate?

Answer (score 3):

The principal components don't correlate. Per definition. They are chosen to be orthogonal.

The data suggest that speed is not correlated with anything else, as it is basically identical to the 3rd PC. However, if that is your question, you should look at the correlation coefficient table, not the PC vectors. Note that the PC vectors don't contain sufficient information about correlations between the variables since you also need eigenvalues.

Interpretation: It looks like a loco can be understood in terms of these three concepts:
1) Size
2) Noiseness adjusted for size
3) Speed

However, you need to look at the eigenvalues also. Do the three first components account for the bulk of the variance in the data?

Comment: how did you come to the conclusion that speed is not correlated with anything else? if you look at the 3rd column of the data you get 0.986 isn't that quite high? shouldn't it have a correlation with something else?

Comment: also what do you mean by a loco?    one of my conclusions was that from the first column you can see noise size and lorry have the same sign so they could be correlated the other 2 dont so noise size lorry could be independent on the speed and electric.. would this conclusion be right?

Comment: I think by saying speed is not correlated the poster meant that because speed is so close to PC3 (as you pointed out) and because the PCs are all orthogonal, then it won't be correlated with any other PC. So you would definitely want to include speed (or PC3) in your analysis.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Thanks, jss367. BY "loco", I thought the subjects in this data set were locos (locomotives)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do with this information. One is to just use the principal components (PCs) directly for further analysis. But another is that you could actually use the original data, and you just know which ones to use based on this.

The first column is your first (and most important) PC. That PC is primarily made up of the size (-.9643). Your next column is the second most important, and fortunately, that's also dominated by a single feature - noise (0.9548). Your third PC is almost completely speed (0.9869).

So you could take either the PCs or those features and see how much of the variation is explained by those alone. To do that, you need to make a scree plot (which you can find tutorials on).